# How to convert ArchiveEntry to InputStream?

Tags: java, apache-commons-compress

I'm reading a `tar.gz` archive using

`ArchiveEntry entry = tarArchiveInputStream.getNextEntry();`

Question: how can I convert this [ArchiveEntry](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/ArchiveEntry.html) to an `InputStream` so I can actually read and process the file to a `String`?

Comment: To clarify, you mean `org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveEntry` from Apache's commons-compress?

Comment: yes I mean commons.compress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use IOUtils to read InputStream fully:

```
import org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils

byte[] buf = new byte[(int) entry.getSize()];
int readed  = IOUtils.readFully(tarArchiveInputStream,buf);

//readed should equal buffer size
if(readed != buf.length) {
 throw new RuntimeException("Read bytes count and entry size differ");
}

String string = new String(buf, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

If your file is in other encoding than utf-8, use that instead of utf-8 in the constructor of string.

Comment: This is probabnly the correct solution as `IOUtils.readFully` can be used directly from `commons.compress`.

Answer (score 4):

It is already an `InputStream`.

```
byte[] buf = new byte[(int) entry.getSize()];
int k = tarArchiveInputStream.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
String s = new String(buf, 0, k);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to read the file one by one, the TarEntry actually holds the File object in it:

> This class represents an entry in a Tar archive. It consists of the entry's header, as well as the entry's File.

Thus just initialize another FileInputStream would be enough:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
String file = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(entry.getFile());
```